# Top-bar appears twice in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, top-bar

I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 with the Multi Monitors Add-On GNOME Shell extension. Suddenly, I have two top-bars on my primary monitor.

[image: both monitors - three top-bars :)]

Rebooting didn't fix the issue, nor did disabling GNOME Shell extensions.

The bottom bar is working as required with extensions running OK. The top one contains only the "Activities", "application-menu" clock and language selector.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue after I installed the Multi Monitors Add-On extension to GNOME Shell in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I uninstalled the extension and rebooted the system. It worked :)